# MySQL - avoid cartesian product on querying?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, cartesian

I have two tables **X** and **Y** , I need total count of rows which has closed (fd_sts_cd = 'C') on today (fulfill_date = CURRENT_DATE).

DB has data

```
select *
from prdsbtmb_mbr_add_info
where fd_sts_cd = 'C' and mbr_id_no='9292138102'-> **12 rows**.

select *
from prdsbtfa_ffl_attempt
where nxt_ffl_dt = CURRENT_DATE and mbr_id_no='9292138102' -> **41 rows**
```

while join them result came differently

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM X a, Y b 
WHERE b.fulfill_date = CURRENT_DATE AND
      a.id = b.id AND
      a.fd_sts_cd = 'C' -> RESULT COUNT::**492**(12*41)
```

I have tried all joins INNER, LEFF, OUTER JOININGS but still result is same.

Could you please clarify me
How we can avoid this Cartesian product and why it's calculating like this?
AND
Is there any solution to avoid that suggest me?

Thanks!!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help explain what you want to do.

Comment: Your second query doesn't match fieldnames from the first one. ¿What happened to `mbr_id_no`? Should it be the same for both tables?

Comment: Yes mbr_id_no column name is same in both tables

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do this using a `join`.  The `join` produces a Cartesian product.

A simple method is just to use subqueries in the `select` clause:

```
select ( (select count(*)
          from prdsbtmb_mbr_add_info
          where fd_sts_cd = 'C' and mbr_id_no = '9292138102'
         ) + 
         (select count(*)
          from prdsbtfa_ffl_attempt
          where nxt_ffl_dt = CURRENT_DATE and mbr_id_no = '9292138102'
         )
        ) as total
```

Comment: But in above query I am not using any join right , why the result was Cartesian Query:SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM X a, Y b 
WHERE b.fulfill_date = CURRENT_DATE AND
      a.id = b.id AND
      a.fd_sts_cd = 'C'.

Comment: and mbr_id_no is not fixed value , in my criteria it should be equal(same) in two tables

Comment: @user3345206 . . . It is only possible to ask the question that you ask.  In this question, it is a fixed value.  If you have *another* question, then ask *another* question, with sample data and desired results.